# AS3: How do I use an image as a color?

Tags: actionscript-3

Under the "Fill and Stroke" option in Flash, you can color a shape as one of the textures from your library. Example: http://i1.minus.com/iban9aRUCI7UTf.png

How can I do this with AS3 code?

Answer (score 1):

If you're drawing with the `Graphics` API, you can use [beginBitmapFill](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginBitmapFill%28%29).

Open the properties of an image in your library and check "*Export for ActionScript*" on the ActionScript tab. Give it a Class name such as "*MyTexture*", and then you can use it like this:

```
var texturedCircle:Sprite = new Sprite();
texturedCircle.graphics.beginBitmapFill(new MyTexture());
texturedCircle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this in two steps.

1. Calculate the average color from bitmap values.  The function below (written by [Soulwire](http://blog.soulwire.co.uk/code/actionscript-3/extract-average-colours-from-bitmapdata)) does this "by looping through the pixels in a BitmapData object, adding up all of the red, green and blue values, dividing them by the total number of pixels and then creating a new colour from the results."

```
function averageColour(source:BitmapData):uint {
    var red:Number = 0;
    var green:Number = 0;
    var blue:Number = 0;
    var count:Number = 0;
    var pixel:Number;

    for (var x:int = 0; x < source.width; x++) {
        for (var y:int = 0; y < source.height; y++) {
            pixel = source.getPixel(x, y);

            red += pixel >> 16 & 0xFF;
            green += pixel >> 8 & 0xFF;
            blue += pixel & 0xFF;

            count++
        }
    }

    red /= count;
    green /= count;
    blue /= count;

    return red << 16 | green << 8 | blue;
}
```

1. Use [ColorTransform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html#ColorTransform%28%29) to apply it.

```
function setColor(obj:Object, color:uint, alpha:Number = 1):void {
    /* Colors the object using uint */

    // Pull the individual primaries
    var r:Number = (color >> 16 ) & 0xFF;
    var g:Number = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
    var b:Number = color & 0xFF;

    obj.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(0,0,0,alpha,r,g,b,0);
}
```